# SSIS Data Flow Task SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am wondering if it is possible to:

1) Develop SSIS Package for Data Flow Task

I am aware of how to do this on a local or network SQLServer,

However is it possible to create a package that uploads to a "remote" sqlserver, ie one that is not on site or on the LAN.

any guidance would be great

Thanks

Comment: Please define "Upload". If a SQL Server is "Remote" = not on site or LAN, how does your package see the SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't see anyway the package could see the other server, I would suggest loading the data to one or more flat files and putting them on an FTP site. Then having the remote server run an SSIS package to pick up the file(s) and process it into their system. This is basically what we do when our clients need data from us.